# Using MPLD3 to make an interactive bar chart

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, mpld3

I am trying to make an interactive bar chart and cannot figure out how to label the boxes. Given a histogram I would like to have it so when the cursor is over the bar the height, or whatever label I want, is displayed. The following code displays the chart but with no labels:

```
hist, bins = np.histogram(df.PER, bins=15)
width = 1 * (bins[1] - bins[0])
center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
boxes = ax.bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width,alpha=0.7,facecolor="red",edgecolor='w')

tooltip = mpld3.plugins.PointHTMLTooltip(boxes[0],labels=bins.tolist(),
                                   voffset=10, hoffset=10)
mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)

mpld3.display()
```

where df.PER is the data from here:

```
0      35.47
1      31.27
2      30.64
3      26.92
4      26.71
5      26.49
6      26.45
7      26.21
8      26.17
9      25.85
10     25.48
11     25.34
12     24.64
13     24.32
14     23.46
15     23.42
16     23.37
17     22.76
18     22.45
19     22.45
20     22.43
21     22.10
22     21.99
23     21.82
24     21.62
25     21.44
26     21.31
27     21.26
28     21.26
29     20.87
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, your code creates a tooltip label for the first bar in the bar chart. You can use a loop to get the rest:

```
for i, box in enumerate(boxes.get_children()):
    tooltip = mpld3.plugins.LineLabelTooltip(box, label=bins[i])
    mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)
```

Here is [a notebook showing the results in context](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/5198492bd1272f0d02f4).

This is a feature that [has been requested previously, and would be nice to offer more directly](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/issues/276), e.g. as `mpld3.plugins.BarTooltip`; patches welcome!